# How can I use the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve a group that I am located in?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to get groups to which logged in user belong by just using `user.read` in API permission or with graph API permission which does not need admin consent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's **not possible** to use just `user.read` permission.

> `user.read` allows you to sign in to the app with your organizational
> account and let the app read your profile. It also allows the app to
> read basic company information.

You could use [Get member groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-getmembergroups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) API to return all the groups that the specified user is a member of.

You must use *`User.Read` and `GroupMember.Read.All`* or *`User.Read` and `Group.Read.All`* permissions to get group memberships for the signed-in user. Which means you need to add GroupMember.Read.All or Group.Read.All permission.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/getMemberGroups
Content-type: application/json

{
  "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
```